# Cleanly accessing nested data in lens-aeson

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

I have the following bit of code, and I'm not happy with it:

```
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.Text hiding (foldl, map)
```

path :: (Applicative f, AsValue t) => [Text] -> (Value -> f Value) -> t -> f t
path [] = error "No path provided" 
path (i:is) = foldl (.) (key i) (map key is)

`path` is meant to be a lens into a nested JSON object. For instance:

```
"{ \"a\": { \"b\": 8} }" ^? path ["a", "b"] == Just (Number 8.0)
```

Currently this works, but the somewhat obvious shortcoming is that the function is not total.

I tried the following definitions:

1. ```
   path is = foldl (.) id (map key is)
   ```
2. ```
   path [] = id
   path (i:is) = foldl (.) (key i) (map key is)
   ```
3. ```
   -- This one doesn't compile
   path [] = _Object
   path (i:is) = foldl (.) (key i) (map key is)
   ```

Running the same code block as above with these definitions yields `Nothing`, instead of the expected `8`.

I'm almost sure this is a case of type juggling that I'm just missing, but I can't figure out how to make this work with a total function. The expected behavior is for `path []` to be a `Lens` which focused on the whole json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_Value` for the empty case:

```
> ("null" :: String) ^? _Value
Just Null
> ("null" :: String) ^? (foldl (.) _Value $ map key ["foo", "bar"])
Nothing
> ("{ \"a\": { \"b\": 8} }" :: String) ^? (foldl (.) _Value $ map key ["a", "b"])
Just (Number 8.0)
```

Also `path` as you describe cannot be a `Lens` as it's partial (as you mention!), at best it is `Traversal`. Yet if you are really sure what you are doing, than you can use [`signular`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.4/lens-4.13/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:singular) to convert `Traversal` into `Lens`.

Comment: A Traversal is fine; this was exactly what I was looking for.